# Single dropdown for many items using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, triggers, twitter-bootstrap

I have a situation where I have a lot of divs (say each div is a product container, with IDs, titles, image etc).

Inside each div, there is also a button that when clicked I would like to toggle a bootstrap dropdown.

Given the number of items, I dont want each item to have its own markup, so I thought I would create one dropdown and show it programmatically through javascript.

Unfortunately, I cannot find a way. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

A brief example follows

@jrharshath, thanks for your prompt reply. I post some code (dummy) and I believe that could help you with your answer!

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="acontainer">
    <span class="aclicker pull-right btn btn-mini"><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i></span>
    <code>ID: w4234234</code><br />
    <img src="..." /><br />
    product title here
  </div>
  (many of the above '.acontainer' repeating)
</div><!-- end container -->


<div class="dropdown" id="popmenu">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to show the #popmenu whenever someone clicks on any .aclicker elements. Just that.

Comment: It would help if you share some code to demonstrate what you already have.

Comment: Is it a popover or a dropdown ? You should paste the code in the question (use the edit link).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use jQuery to move it around whenever an `.aclicker` element is clicked.

#### JavaScript

```
var $popmenu = $('#popmenu')
  , last;

$('body').on('click.dropdown', '.aclicker', function() {

  // Make sure it's not already open here
  $popmenu.hasClass('open') && last === this ?
    $popmenu.removeClass('open') : // close it

    // otherwise, reposition
    $popmenu
      .css({
        top: this.offsetTop + this.offsetHeight,
        left: this.offsetLeft + this.offsetWidth - 172
      })
      .children('.dropdown-menu')
      .dropdown('toggle'); // then open it

  last = this; // save reference
  return false;
});​
```

#### CSS

```
#popmenu {
  position: absolute;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/PfzWb/)